# Mongodb Aggregation grouping with leave the field

Tags: mongodb

After applying the aggregation

```
db.grades.aggregate([
     {$match: {'type': 'homework'}},
     {$sort: {'student_id':1, 'score':1}}
])
```

got the result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("50906d7fa3c412bb040eb579"),
            "student_id" : 0,
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 14.8504576811645
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57a"),
            "student_id" : 0,
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 63.98402553675503
        }, 
    ...
```

How to modify the request to leave documents with a minimum value *score* and get a result which kept the field *id*. For example, in such a way:

```
  {
            "_id" : ObjectId("50906d7fa3c412bb040eb579"),
            "score" : 14.8504576811645
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: So what you want is the document with the lowest score for every student? Or just the one result with the lowest score?

Comment: Yes, the lowes score for every student, but so that there was a field "_id".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a homework question from the education site? I can't remember, but this is fairly trivial.

```js
db.grades.aggregate([
   { "$match": { type: 'homework' } },
   { "$sort": {student_id: 1, score: 1} },
   { "$group": { 
       "_id": "$student_id", 
       "doc": { "$first": "$_id"}, 
       "score": { "$first": "$score"} 
   }},
   { "$sort: { "_id": 1 } },
   { "$project": {
       "_id": "$doc",
       "score": 1 
   }}
])
```

All this does is use [$first](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) to get the first result when grouping by `student_id`. By first it means exactly that, so this is only useful after sorting and is different from [$min](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) which would take the smallest value from the grouped results.

So if you got part of the way there, not only do you keep the first score, but you also do the same operation on the `_id` value as well.

The additional sort is only there so the results don't trip you up, because they are likely to appear in the reverse order of `student_id`. Finally there is just a small use of [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to get the document form that you want.

Comment: Yes, you are right it is a problem with the edu-site. I decided it successfully, but used a Python script. I was wondering how to solve this problem using aggregation. 


Thanks for your help and operation `$first`!